# Overriding "constants" from parent class python

Tags: python, inheritance, constants, conventions

I have a simple inheritance setup as follows:

```
class A:
    CONST_VAR = "aaa"
    # more code where CONST_VAR does not change
    # ...

class B(A):
    CONST_VAR = "bbb"
    # more code where CONST_VAR does not change
    # ...
```

So within each class CONST_VAR is indeed constant, however it clearly changes between classes. Is CAPITAL_CASE the correct convention for CONST_VAR? Can anyone point to the appropriate PEP or any style guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) recommends using capital case for constants, but I usually interpret this as "module-level constants".

On the other hand, this is a class variable and PEP8 doesn't specify the naming for class variables.

But if we look at [Google Style Guide for Python](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html), here it clearly states that class constants should also be capitalized:

> Global/Class Constants    CAPS_WITH_UNDER

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all uppercase is the convention for constants.  See [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#constants).  The same is true within a class, you can see that through out the standard library and the documentation.

Here is an [enum example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum):

```
class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3
```

Here is another from the [http module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html#module-http):

```
>>> from http import HTTPStatus
>>> HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND
<HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND: 404>
```

Answer (score 0):

These are two different constants, `A.CONST_VAR` and `B.CONST_VAR`.  Clearly all capitals is correct.